# Softlayer API: how to update CCI's OS username and password

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use the following API and parameters to update cci's username and password, but kept getting bad request error. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/12345.json

Method: PUT

```
{
    "parameters": [
        "operatingSystem": 
        {
            "passwords ": [
                {
                    "username": "root1",
                    "password" : "Test1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

**Retrieves the password's identifier from the vm**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/getSoftwareComponents?objectMask=mask[passwords]

Method: Get
```

Replace **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$vsiId** with you own information

You will get a result like this:

```
hardwareId": null
"id": 345676755
"manufacturerLicenseInstance": "C412F72A-1BB1-4C07-9467-E55729234F8E"
"passwords": [1]
0:  {
"createDate": "2016-06-09T11:10:28-03:00"
"id": 122333
"modifyDate": "2016-09-06T11:19:18-03:00"
"password": "Cochabamba"
"port": null
"softwareId": 11209641
"username": "Ruber"
"software": null
}
}
```

**Then you can update using the following call:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/$passwordId/editObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "username":"usernameTest",
         "password":"Password*-"
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$passwordId** with you own information, in this case the **$passwordId** is: **122333**

**Note:** Keep in mind that the password is only changed for tracking, it won't take effect in the server

Comment: Thank you, Ruber! I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: The way you suggested works great! Thank you very much, Ruber!